# Using Replace function in condition statements

Tags: sql

I have to work on a script written by my previous co-worker. Now, a part of the script doesn't make sense for me; I think the replace function is redundant and I would like to know your opinion on it.

```
WHEN (ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(x, 4, ','))), '.', '')) = 1)

THEN CAST(REPLACE(dbo.UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS(x, 4, ','), '.', '') AS BIGINT)
```

So, for the first line,

1- UFN_SEPARATES_COLUMNS function separates the 4th character based on the comma that comes after it, and removes the beginning space and trailing space.

2- Also, if there is any dots, it will be replaced by ''

3-Finally, it evaluates whether the 4th character has a numeric value

Now, the part that I don't understand comes from the second line. If we have already used the replace function to remove the dots, why are we using it again?
Thanks

Comment: `WHEN exp1 THEN exp2` exp1 and exp2 are fully independent

Comment: First line is a condition and second line is what  is desired output.. first replace doesn't changes the cast format automatically

Comment: @nina_dev . .. Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace()` in the `when` condition has nothing to do with the `replace()` in the `then` condition.

No data is being modified "in place".  In fact, SQL `select` statements do not modify data at all.

So, you need to repeat the expression in the `when`.  You could use a subquery, CTE, or `apply` if you wanted to type the expression only once.